# Docker install lvm plugin

Tags: docker, go

Im trying to docker LVM plugin but facing some issues with GO.

```
 pr@pr-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ go version
go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64
pr@pr-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ make
go-md2man -in man/docker-lvm-plugin.8.md -out docker-lvm-plugin.8
/usr/bin/go build -o docker-lvm-plugin .
make: /usr/bin/go: Command not found
make: *** [lvm-plugin-build] Error 127
```

Here is my GO version.

```
pr@pr-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ go version
go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the makefile has a hard-coded absolute path to the go binary at `/usr/bin/go` (bad makefile, no biscuit!) - if your binary is not there, create a symlink to it at that location.